# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when I start hbase

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hbase, apache-zookeeper

There are three node3(node1,node2,node3) in my cluster.I  have installed `hadoop-2.5.2`,`zookeeper-3.5.4-cdh5.10.0`,`jdk-7u67-linux-x64` on my Centos server ,they all work well.

Then I install `hbase-0.98.6-cdh5.3.0`,I think my configuration is all right,but when I use command `start-hbase.sh` to start hbase,only regionserver start,the master doesn't start.

This is the result of command `jps`:

```
[zjt@node1 ~]$ jps

2130 HRegionServer

27945 Jps

11487 NameNode

11621 DataNode

12117 QuorumPeerMain

[zjt@node2 ~]$ jps

21282 QuorumPeerMain

16159 Jps

13998 HRegionServer

20914 DataNode

[zjt@node3 ~]$ jps

21282 QuorumPeerMain

16159 Jps

13998 HRegionServer

20914 DataNode
```

I looked at the master log file,it shows this:

```
 2021-04-27 15:56:28,537 FATAL [master:node1:60000] master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.                                   
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray(II[BI[BIILjava/lang/String;JZ)V                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray(Native Method)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.calculateChunkedSumsByteArray(NativeCrc32.java:86)                                 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DataChecksum.calculateChunkedSums(DataChecksum.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.writeChecksumChunks(FSOutputSummer.java:197)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close(DFSOutputStream.java:2130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.setVersion(FSUtils.java:654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.setVersion(FSUtils.java:629)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.checkVersion(FSUtils.java:586)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.checkRootDir(MasterFileSystem.java:462)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.createInitialFileSystemLayout(MasterFileSystem.java:153)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:129)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:808)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:613)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2021-04-27 15:56:28,538 INFO  [master:node1:60000] master.HMaster: Aborting
2021-04-27 15:56:28,556 DEBUG [master:node1:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping service threads                                   
2021-04-27 15:56:28,556 INFO  [master:node1:60000] ipc.RpcServer: Stopping server on 60000
2021-04-27 15:56:28,556 INFO  [RpcServer.listener,port=60000] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.listener,port=60000: stopping                                   
2021-04-27 15:56:28,556 INFO  [master:node1:60000] master.HMaster: Stopping infoServer
2021-04-27 15:56:28,567 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopped                                   
2021-04-27 15:56:28,567 INFO  [RpcServer.responder] ipc.RpcServer: RpcServer.responder: stopping                                   
2021-04-27 15:56:28,619 INFO  [master:node1:60000] mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:60010                                   
2021-04-27 15:56:28,830 INFO  [master:node1:60000] zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x279111b88470006 closed                                   
2021-04-27 15:56:28,830 INFO  [master:node1:60000] master.HMaster: HMaster main thread exiting                                   
2021-04-27 15:56:28,830 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: HMaster Aborted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:194)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)                                   
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2822)
2021-04-27 15:56:28,831 INFO  [main-EventThread] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

I have tried to reboot every node of cluster,reinstall hbase ,remove the HBase node in ZooKeeper,but   no use.

this is my `hbase-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://node1:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>node1,node2,node3</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Could you please help me out problem this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At a glance I'd say that this looks like a version clash - I'd double-check the compatibility of the services you're running.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely.
The cluster mentioned in the question was set up by me using the cloud servers,one is centos7.6,the other two are centos 7.3.They're in different segments of the net.

I also tried to set up a cluster on VMware workstation on my laptop, I use the same version ,Strangely,they all work well.